# Running cutycapt from PHP on my Ubunty Server

Tags: php

I have installed CutyCapt on my Ubuntu server, with the following commandline command I get the expected screen cap from the website I want:

```
cutycapt --url=http://amazingjokes.com --out=crap/test32443.jpg
```

No I want to do the same from within a PHP script. I tried this:

```
echo `cutycapt --url=http://amazingjokes.com --out=crap/test32443.jpg`;
var_dump( shell_exec( 'cutycapt --url=http://amazingjokes.com --out=crap/test32443.jpg' ) );
var_dump( system( 'cutycapt --url=http://amazingjokes.com --out=crap/test32443.jpg' ) );
```

none of these 3 lines seem to render any effect at all. Loading time is way to short to make the actual capture of the website I'm looking for, and no files are generated either. Also, there are no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have checked by apache logs... so far it seems to be the X-server that cutycapt can not connect to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error logs of Apache. When this shows: "cannot connect to x server" you'll need an X server running. This can be installed like this (install a light weight version of a GUI server):

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

then change the php system command to run cutycapt in this X server:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1280x1200x24" cutycapt --url=http://amazingjokes.com --out=crap/test32443.jpg
```